# Can a non-usb camera (mounted camera sensor) be published with topic & info?

Tags: ros, image, topic, buffer, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Experts,

I am naive to ROS and its environment. Forgive, if the solution is straight forward.
As a task, i need to use a camera sensor  (not a USB camera) mounted on my arm based target board. I need it to publish the camera info and topic, to be able to use as input to LSD-SLAM library which i am able to make it work on the board.
I've come to know that if the camera node (/dev/video*) is available, using gscam, one can publish the topic and info and use the camera stream. Correct me if i am wrong.

However, to make things worse, my camera driver is tightly looped with userspace library, and does not gives anything out on /dev/video* node. The only way to access the camera output frame is to use some script which eventually returns frames as buffers.
So, given the above scenario, is it possible to create and publish camera info and topic for which no camera node exists and the only way to get captured frame's data is through some function returning a frame-buffer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198245/can-a-non-usb-camera-(mounted-camera-sensor)-be-published-with-topic-&-info?/) by [makc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20928/makc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. In the end, all camera nodes that currently exist in ROS are just programs that retrieve frames from the underlying Linux device / frame buffer / IP / firewire connection or something similar.

You'll have to write something yourself though, as there doesn't seem to be an existing ROS camera driver for yor setup.

Just make sure you publish the right topics (at least `image_raw` and `camera_info`). You may want to look at existing nodes for inspiration.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-03**:
it is also recommended to use image_transport as your image publisher rather then the typical ros publsiher